# Customize Button in xcode5

Tags: uibutton, customization, xcode5

I am trying to add a button into my app. I want the button to be just like the button used in old version of Xcode. that is round rectangular button. Is there a way to make my button in Xcode 5 as like in Xcode 4.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following framework and import it in the header file.

```
import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

In your loadView method add following lines

```
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10; // this value vary as per your desire
yourButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Don't forget to change the text colour and button background.

This should do it.

Comment: Is there a default way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

in loadView:

```
[self.button.layer setCornerRadius:8.];
[self.button.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```